# in vb6, how to query access records, then order by specific ids

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007, charindex

```
select * from [main] where id in (33,11,22) order by id
```

if i using this query, i will get the recordset order by this:

```
11
22
33
```

but i want to the return recordset by this order (same as `id in (33,11,22)` order):

```
33
11
22
```

by google i understand we can use this to realize:

```
select * from [main] where id in (33,11,22) order by charindex(ltrim(id),'33,11,22')
```

but the problem is vb6 does not support `charindex`, I got the error `The expression contains undefined function call CHARINDEX` when I using it.

so what can I do in vb6? thank you.

**update**: by @MarkL's suggest, I'm using `instr` to instead of `CHARINDEX`, the query running but not running as expectation, the return recordset with this order:

```
33
22
11
```

thanks.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: this QA may solve you problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/15072297/1844933

Comment: @user1844933 I using access 2007, thank you.

Comment: Not a vb6 issue.  Access (perhaps more specifically the Jet or ODBC drivers, whatever you're using) doesn't support `charindex` (thats a SQL Server function, and perhaps other databases).  The `InStr` function might work - see [this MS Access doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/instr-function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from [main] where id in (33,11,22) order by InStr("33,11,22", id)
```

Should give you what you want.

A better version to guard against ID 11 matching "111,222" would be:

```
select * from [main] where id in (33,11,22) order by InStr(",33,11,22,", "," & id & ",")
```

A set based alternative would be to have a 2nd "matches" table with a AutoNumber RowNum column & a Value column into which you insert 33, 11, 22 (in order) allowing for:

```
select * from [main] inner join matches on (matches.id = [main].id) order by rownum
```

Comment: it works! this help me much time, can not find answer on google for hours, thank you very much, best regards.